# ASP.NET WEB API with SQL(Web Forms)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I was going through a tutorial located here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/772479/Simple-Steps-for-Using-Web-API-in-ASP-NET-Web-Form. They seem to hard code their data in the controller(still trying to wrap my head around this MVC concepts hence web forms for now)  and i wanted to know how can I change it to rather fetch the data from SQL SERVER.Do I place the ADO.NET connection in the same section and do a  normal datareader.Is the more that needs to be done.

```
public class StudentsController : ApiController
{
    Student[] students = new Student[]
    {
        new Student { StudentID = 1, FirstName = "Imran",   LastName = "Ghani"  },
        new Student { StudentID = 2, FirstName = "Salman",  LastName = "Ahmad"  },
        new Student { StudentID = 3, FirstName = "Rehan",   LastName = "Ahmad   },
        new Student { StudentID = 4, FirstName = "Zeeshan", LastName = "Khalid" }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return students;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you go work through a tutorial!

Comment: I have been searching for tutorials specifically with Web forms WEB API and SQL but the web there is an MVC craze

Comment: That's because WebApi *is* part of the MVC framework. You don't need to know anything about WebForms to answer your question.

Comment: That is obvious know that it is but i am asking specifically for web forms.Note the database  and the application I am trying to modify were done in web forms and ADO.NET. No Entity Famework

Comment: I think you are confused as to what WebApi and MVC are. WebForms and WebApi are not linked in any way nor can you join the two together other than your WebForms application calling the API over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

In general the flow will be

- A request comes into IIS
- IIS maps the request to a controller method
- The method is called along with any parameters passed
- Within the method you get a database connection from the pool
- Read any necessary data
- Format and return the data

Of course there will be instances were this isn't the case, but hopefully this will help you get a handle on what is going on.